# jenkins cant see summary of changes of build output

Tags: jenkins, mercurial

We recently upgraded mercurial version and suddenly in my jenkins i can't see the changes  of the code in the build summary output of build's ..? I used to see the changes summary before the upgrade.. please find the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1fB3.png)   . please help me . My current jenkins version is 1.613 and  mercurial version is 3.7.3

Comment: This is not Google buddy! 
If you are really looking for answers; you might have to mention specific versions and more explanatory question.

Comment: Perhaps someone knows a solution if you add the affected versions (version numbers) of mercurial and jenkins.